# Discord bot does not respond to messages on servers

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```py
import discord

# Create a client instance
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.typing = False
intents.presences = False
intents.messages = True  # Enable intents for messages
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

# Handle the on_ready event
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as {client.user.name}')

    # Set the online status
    await client.change_presence(
        status=discord.Status.do_not_disturb, activity=discord.Game(name="TESTS")
    )

# Handle the on_message event
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    print(f'Received message: {message.content}')
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('!hello'):
        await message.channel.send('Hello!')

# Run the bot
client.run("My token")
```

if i send message on a server bot not responde (i gave him all of premissions)
i asked chat gpt and it don't help :'(

[image: discord screenshot]

Comment: Does it print the recieved message? By "I gave it all the permissions" you don't mean intents, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a difference between the [intents.message](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Intents.messages) and the [intents.message_content](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Intents.message_content).

While the first is a general intent to have access to the message context, it does Not have access to message content within a Guild, as it became a private intent about a year ago (You can check the Dev notes [here](https://support-dev.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/4404772028055-Message-Content-Privileged-Intent-FAQ)); It does however have access to the content within a DM.

Therefore, in order for you to have access to the content of both Guild and DM message contents, you need to declare the intents to `message_content` as below:

`intents.message_content = True`

Answer (score -1):

If you're working with discord.py newest version you should declare the type of variable you are using:

```
async def on_message(message:discord.Message)
```

This sets the variable to a discord message. The rest of the code should work.